# TFS 2010 deploy HTML without build

Tags: msbuild

I need to copy HTML files to a local network server whenever they are checked in to TFS.  I have been searching the net for the past 7 hours, and have been pulling my hair out attempting to create MSBuild scripts without success.

I need a set of simple steps which cause files to be copied with no build needed (I don't have a project file, and don't actually need to compile anything.)

The location of the server is on the network, and is accessible via Windows Explorer.